# What are some good uses of Autorun (autorun.inf file) for USB drives?

Tags: windows, configuration, usb-flash-drive

I mostly use that right now just to give my USB drive a name and an icon.  What else can you do with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None. [Autorun should be disabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd452420.aspx). This is one way Conficker spread onto fully patched Windows systems.

Comment: Yes, we can't patch the users, can we.  Social engineering is definitely a problem there.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun#Attack_vectors

Answer (score 4):

To further rain on your parade, its worth noting that in Windows 7, Autorun on USB drives is disabled, and the only option users will be given is to open the folder in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I seen people put a pop-up message with contact information in case the USB drive is lost.

That way when the device is found and plugged into a machine, the contact info is displayed.

I always agree they are a security risk though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program which asks me what I'm going to do on it (development, "secure" browsing) and then opens the right apps (which BTW, are on the drive too). Other than that, the [PortableApps Menu](http://portableapps.com) is quite nice.